# Tag user in comment not working

Tags: discussion, support

In reference to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59625/how-can-the-identification-code-be-received-before-the-wormhole-is-created), I made a [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59625/how-can-the-identification-code-be-received-before-the-wormhole-is-created/59721?noredirect=1#comment119982_59721) on an answer. I then realized I was saying the same thing, so commented again. It's late, so I forgot to tag the other user. I went to edit my comment to add the @ tag, and it wouldn't take/save/show up. Whats the deal? Note the other user in question has a username of only three characters, and the comment tag system only looks at the first three characters. Could this be the reason?

Looking again, I notice that I had tried to tag the user in my first comment, which it appears to not be there. What gives?

Asking on meta, since I don't think this would be a site specific issue.

Comment: See, in particular, item #10 at the linked question in the "details" section of the answer.